# How to dual-boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

This question has been asked several times, I am aware of that. However, the tutorials/responses that I have looked at mention partitioning the hard drive with certain specifications using GParted, which I don't know how to use or even how to open. I am running a Windows 10 Home system, and I would like to install Ubuntu alongside it (for various reasons). I already have the Windows 10 installation media and Ubuntu 15 installation media (on a USB drive). Where do I go from here? I would like to have both systems installed on my 250 GB SSD, so that I can use my 1 TB HDD for storage. I have 8 GB of 1066 DDR3 RAM as well. If any other information on my system is needed, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

GParted is simple to use. If you run the Live Ubuntu USB and select Try Ubuntu, it will load up Ubuntu from the USB. Click on the Ubuntu icon in the top left of the screen or hit your Windows key. Type GParted, and click on Gparted Partition Manager to open it. It will automatically scan for drives. In the top right corner of the window you will be able to select the drive you want to manage. They'll be called /dev/sda  /dev/sdb and so on. They should also tell you the size next to them. Select your SSD. Make sure it isn't mounted by right-clicking and clicking Unmount (If it's already unmounted it'll say Mount instead). Then Click the green arrow on top to resize the partition. A new window will open where you can drag the ends to the size you want. Probably about 150GB for Windows and 100GB for Ubuntu, but however you want. Then click on the gray area you just created, and click the White page with the plus symbol to create a new partition. Select the type you want (Probably go for NTFS and then when you install ubuntu it'll format it to the kind it needs, ext4, I believe). You may want to add a label to distinguish them later on. Click ok. Now click the green check mark to perform these actions. Don't interrupt it while it's messing with ther partitions. Once you're done, you can install ubuntu on the new partition you just created!

Comment: How do I actually run the program though? I'm not exactly sure how to use ISO files.

Comment: Right. I recommend you use Rufus (it's free). http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Once downloaded, run Rufus with your USB drive plugged in. Select the USB drive in the Device menu, click on the little disk image button next to the Create a bootable disk using and select the iso you just downloaded. Then click start. It will ask you if you really want to format the drive, which you need to do, so make sure there's no important info on it. Rufus will take about 7 minutes to complete (on my system anyway).

Then turn off your computer, and when you boot, boot off of the USB drive.

Comment: But I don't want to boot from the Linux drive, I want to dual-boot the system instead of having to plug in the drive every time I want to use Linux,

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. However, to install Ubuntu on your SSD you will need to boot off of the USB. Once Ubuntu is installed, you won't have to boot off of the USB again.

Comment: Ok, I now have the Rufus program, what settings should I use for it? MBR or GPT (I am running a UEFI system)? What file system? FAT32, NTFS, UDF, or exFAT? What does the cluster size do? It also says "Create a bootable image using..." should I choose ISO?

Comment: Just use the default settings. So MBR for BIOS or UEFI (Although MBR for UEFI should also work), Fat32, Default Cluster Size. Once you select the ISO you are wanting to install, it shoudl default to ISO Image, if not, go ahead and select it. You can change the label to whatever you like.

Comment: When I clicked the Start button, I got this popup: http://imgur.com/G7hgbUe. What does it mean and what should I say?

Comment: Go ahead and click yes for it to download the necessary backend it needs to create a bootable USB with that ISO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33131/discussion-between-clefspeare13-and-roboticplayer).